# Code Inspection in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm does not detect undefined variables, when they are passed to a function by reference.

```
func1($a);
func2($a);

function func1(&$a) {
}
function func2($a) {
}
```

In this example, only the variable `$a` in the invocation of `func2` is highlighted.

How can I change that?

Comment: Read the second note: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: my question is about php storm, not php

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with php strom, just with how php works.

Comment: my question is about the way phpstorm detects possible errors in the code. Passing a undefined variable per reference might be totally correct PHP, but is still a possible error source that could easily be detected by an intelligent IDE.

Comment: PHP storm can't spot what logical errors you made in your code. It can only detect PHP errors/warnings.

Comment: @Rizier123 Not really. For instance, it warns about duplicate array indexes, which are anyway legal.

Comment: @Risier123 Wrong. PHP Storm can even detect violations of naming conventions.

Comment: What are your settings under: File > Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) > Project Settings > Inspections > PHP > Undefined > Undefined variable ?

Comment: @Ferenjito With your logic `$matches` should be marked as undefined in `preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)`. Not a bug but desired behaviour as per https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-25617 & https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4867

Answer (score 0):

Put under function func1 something like this:

```
/**
 * func1
 *
 * @param string $a
 * @return mixed
 */
```

Its better to describe all methods and properties by PHP Annotations. And change `string` if it is another type.